# "Error: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()" no Select

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Fazendo o método para selecionar todos os dados de uma tabela, porém está me retornando error.
console: Banco aberto.

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1    
> No value specified for parameter 1
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2176)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2100)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:931)
>     at persistence.ProdutoDao.findAll(ProdutoDao.java:27)
>     at persistence.ProdutoDao.main(ProdutoDao.java:51)
> ```

Método findAll:

```
    public List<Produto> findAll()throws Exception{
    open();//metodo q abre a conexao com o banco
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(SELECT); //constante select*from produto
        stmt.execute();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        List<Produto> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        while(rs.next()){
            lista.add(new Produto(
                    rs.getInt(1),
                    rs.getString(2),
                    rs.getString(3),
                    rs.getString(4),
                    rs.getDouble(5) 
                    )
            );

        }
        close();//metodo que fecha a conexao com o banco
        return lista;
}
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         try {
            ProdutoDao pd = new ProdutoDao();
            System.out.println(pd.findAll());
         } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println("Nao listou " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Pelo jeito a constante está errada, ela chama `INSERT` e o código parace de um select.

Comment: Desculpa, só fiz confusão com o método que vem acima dele, a constante é SELECT mesmo e na hora de copiar pra cá eu fiz a confusão. a String recebe "select * from produto;"

Answer (score 1):

O erro `No value specified for parameter 1` geralmente ocorre quando você possui uma consulta que espera um determinado parâmetros porém este parâmetros não está sendo passado.

No código apresentado acima você informou uma constante contendo a consulta:

```
 stmt = con.prepareStatement(INSERT);
```

Provavelmente o conteúdo desta constante possui algo como `select*from produto where id=?`.
Neste caso basta fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE id=?"); 
stmt.setLong(1, id);
stmt.execute();
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Onde id é uma variável que contem o id a ser buscado.

Claro que você deve adaptar ao seu caso, não sei quais são as colunas e parâmetros que você deseja passar.

Comment: Nesse caso eu fiz de uma forma que buscasse todas as colunas e seus dados na tabela, mas como está dando erro vou tentar da forma que vc sugeriu, obrigado!

Comment: estranho porque como disse este erro geralmente ocorre quando a consulta espera um parâmetro e o mesmo não foi passado.

Comment: Pois é!Obrigado pela ajuda!